# Create an aar file and perform checking

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, module

I'm new on Android studio and I'd like to have some suggestions if it's possible to create an AAR with the following characteristics:
- save and check by the owner how many times it was opened
- integrity of the file
- delete automatically if the conditions are not satisfied
If you have also some suggestions on where I can get material about Android studio and how to create modules it will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can analyze the .AARs and view there licence keys, that should be all you need if any one tapered with the key would no longer be valid and android studio would not let it be used, to create a new module go file > new module. for info on android studio go to [this link](https://developer.android.com)